# Change in taxes with change in residency status in U.S.?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, taxes, mutual-funds

I am on a student F-1 visa in the United States, and have invested in a number of U.S. mutual funds through Vanguard.
Questions:

1. Do I count as a non-resident alien OR a resident alien for tax purposes?
2. If I leave the U.S. after my studies, what are the implications for the tax that will be incurred on my investment, and how would I pay them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like F visa students are not counted as residents, [according to this](http://www.irs.gov/businesses/small/international/article/0,,id=96352,00.html).

In general, resident status is determined by the [substantial presence test](http://www.irs.gov/businesses/small/international/article/0,,id=96352,00.html):

To meet this test, you must be physically present in the United States on at least:

- 31 days during the current year, and
- 183 days during the 3-year period that includes the current year and the 2 years immediately before that, counting:

  - All the days you were present in the current year, and
  - 1/3 of the days you were present in the first year before the current year, and
  - 1/6 of the days you were present in the second year before the current year.

Also, of course, if you had green card you'd be resident too. But F-visa students seem to be exempt.

Comment: OK, so sounds like I am a non-resident alien. I guess I will stay this way when I leave the country? What would be the tax rate for a non-resident alien?

Comment: This is **not** true: F1 students are not generally exempt and considered non-resident aliens: After 5 years in the US on F1 visa you are considered **resident alien for tax purposes**.